How I can align equations with amsmath
I use amsmath for my paper but I find that my equations are not aligned. It looks like equality is not under the equality. Directive align* also doesn't work. I have the issue with multiple labels

Just code:
\begin{align} 
g_{kl}(0) = \delta_{kl},  \nonumber \\ 
\partial_n{g_{kl}}(0) = 0 \label{eqn: partial}
\end{align}


You may want to look through the amsmath manual.   But in short, it aligns your equations on the & character, which you want just before your =.  Without any &, TeX puts an extra & at the end of your lines, so their right sides line up.
